# Retrieve items from table that has value1 but not value2

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `t1` (below is a very simplified version of real table)

```
Name Subject Pass
A    Math    Yes
A    English  No
A    Science  No
B    Math     No
B    English  No
B    Science  No
```

I need to query all names that haven't passed in any subject (pass = no)

`Select distinct(name) from t1 where Pass = 'No' and Pass <> 'Yes' 
doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

```
Select distinct(name) from t1 where Pass = 'No' and Pass <> 'Yes'
```

This doesn't work because the expression in the WHERE clause is evaluated for one row at a time, not for the whole group. Your `Pass` column can't simultaneously have  values of 'No' and 'Yes' on any given row, therefore the query above will only filter for rows where Pass = 'No' regardless of whether there is some other row with 'Yes'.

For a solution to your query, you could write it this way:

```
SELECT name
FROM t1
GROUP BY name
HAVING SUM(Pass = 'Yes') = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use aggregation.  Assuming `pass` only takes on those two values:

```
select name
from t1
group by name
having min(pass) = 'No' and max(pass) = 'No';
```

This checks that the only `pass` values for a given name is `'No'` -- the minimum and maximum are the same.

If you have a separate table of names, a more efficient version is probably:

```
select n.name
from names n
where not exists (select 1 from t1 where t1.name = n.name and t1.pass = 'Yes');
```

This works best with an index on `t1(name, pass)`.

Comment: Can you please explain this?

Comment: Didn't you mean to introduce a `HAVING` clause instead of using `where min(pass) = ... and max(pass) = ...`?

Comment: @stickybit . . . Sometimes, I wonder myself what I was thinking.  Thank you, it's all fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Your title and description don't really match - but I assume you're after something like this (the old school approach)...

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.name  
           FROM my_table x  
           LEFT 
           JOIN my_table y 
             ON y.name = x.name 
            AND y.pass = 1 -- or 'yes', if you insist
          WHERE y.name IS NULL
```